# Sending the data saved in the database in the Django project to an e-mail address

Tags: django, postgresql, email

First of all, I'm new to this and I want to do something like this. I want to filter the database records in my project that I created with Django and send them to an e-mail address in a certain format. I have no idea how to do this, can you help me with this?

Comment: What do you want to do ? Do you want to send an email every time a record is inserted ?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/email/  https://www.sitepoint.com/django-send-email/  I just typed "django email" in google

Comment: No I want to post all records on a daily basis. For example I want to send all records on 10/24/2022.

Comment: checkout django-celery, it allows you to schedule task. You should be able to schedule daily mails with it :p  https://pypi.org/project/django-celery/

Comment: Checkout this so question, I think it is a duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63552113/gmail-schedule-send-email-in-django

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gmail Schedule Send Email in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63552113/gmail-schedule-send-email-in-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use django celery to schedule daily mails.

This SO post answers it pretty well : [Gmail Schedule Send Email in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63552113/gmail-schedule-send-email-in-django)